# multiple url get async await axios VUE.JS

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios

Probably this is a very stupid question, i'm new in vue.js and javascript, so please forgive me if the question is not properly explained or the answer is simple...  I have a problem I wanted to get from two different api and then display it for.

```
async mounted() {
const { data } = await this.axios.get(
  "http://some-ip/api/get"
).then(response => {
    this.items = response.data.data.items
  })
;
const { data2 } = await this.axios.get(
  "http://some-ip/api2/get"
).then(response => {
    this.items2 = response.data.data.items
  })
;
```

First api works perfectly, the second no works...
Any good soul who can help this newbie? (if can explain the why of the solution as well, for understand, will be amazing!!)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `the second no works` in what way? are both really fetching from the same URL? have you perhaps considered `.catch` to debug your code? do both responses have a `data.data` ... so many questions, so little characters left

Comment: my mistake in the post above   first is "http://some-ip/api/get" and second "http://some-ip/api2/get"

Comment: this is what the api structure looks like.. {
    "name": null,
    "data": {
        "objectsType": "models",
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "ghz",
                "id": 85,
                "name": {
                    "value": "speed"
                },
for this data.data...

Comment: perhaps you should check the browser console for errors - since you won't post actual URL's we can't possibly tell you which particular reason the second request fails, since there are so many reasons a request can fail ...unauthorised, bad request, resource not found, internal server error, network error, CORS error .... that's off the top of my head

Comment: that's all good, and looks like there would be a `data.data` (I hate how axios returns data :p ) ... but if the request failed, the result will NOT be that --- that's what the browser *developer* tools console is for - developers to debug code

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to destructure `data2` from Axios response which doesn't exist on that object, only `data` does. You have to use `data` to get the actual response data.

Axios response schema for reference: https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema

Consider this example as it destructures the data props but sets the name to data2:

```
const { data: data2 } = await this.axios.get(
  "http://some-ip/api2/get"
).then(response => {
    this.items2 = response.data.data.items
  })
;
```